# Google Sheets : Populate cell with text if range of cells contains a certain word

Tags: google-sheets

I've been searching all over and can't get this right. I want the formula to search for the word "Cash" in a range of cells and when found - populate the adjacent cell with the word "Cash".

```
=IF(ISTEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(H2,"Cash")),"Cash","False")
```

This formula only works in individual cells. I can't get a range going with it in conditional formatting.

I know this seems like an odd thing to do with "Cash" and "Cash".  I'm after the mechanics and will tweak it later for something else.

Answer (score 0):

try in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(H2:H); "cash"); "Cash"; ))
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  I tried in conditional formatting and just putting it in a cell in row 2.

Comment: @tripey can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: OK! Im looking right now to see how I do that

Comment: Do I share it with you via email?

Comment: @tripey https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OcihJI1FEK8E4D0HIrmmbtENyEvMPHAx_qP2EzryBmw/edit#gid=0